# Use a bash script to load environment variables from a file hosted remotely

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file hosted on an s3 bucket that has the following format:

```
var1=value1
var2=value2
var3=value3
```

I wish to create a bash script on my Linux box that when executed, set environment variables from the remote file. SO far, I have tried the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

export $(aws s3 cp s3://secret-bucket/file.txt - | sed -e /^$/d -e /^#/d | xargs)
```

```
#!/bin/sh

eval $(aws s3 cp s3://secret-bucket/file.txt - | sed 's/^/export /')
```

But none of them seems to work because when I execute `printenv` the variables I need do not show. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are these scripts being run through User Data, or are you invoking them yourself after login?

Comment: I am loading these variables after building a Docker container. I hope that helps?

Comment: The `#!/bin/sh` header looks like you are executing this as a separate script, meaning the assignments will be evaluated, then forgotten when the script exits. (Also, don't use Bash syntax in `sh` scripts; perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: If you could ssh to that host, try following `sshfs user@host:/patho/to/file ~/tmpdir;
source ~/tmpdir/file_with_vars`

Comment: @tripleee thank you. The link was very helpful in getting me to understand. I will dig in more to find something that works mainly for my use case.